# Iterate through ReactJS components onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, return, components

The goal is have this functionally work as a slider/slideshow.

## **Example Modal Components:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Modal_1 = () => {

  return (

    <li id="intro-res-slide" class="active">
        <div>
            <h2>Hi Im Mariah</h2>
        </div>
    </li>

  )

}

export default Modal_1;
```

## **Presentational Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';


// Modals
import Modal_1 from "./modals/Modal_1.js"
import Modal_2 from "./modals/Modal_2.js"
import Modal_3 from "./modals/Modal_3.js"
import Modal_4 from "./modals/Modal_4.js"
import Modal_5 from "./modals/Modal_5.js"

const _modals = [ Modal_1, Modal_2, Modal_3, Modal_4, Modal_5 ]


const HelperModalRender = (props) => (

  <div class="tool-slides active slideshow">

      <ul>
        {/* ITERATE THROUGH MODALS HERE */}
        { _modals[props.currentSlide] }
      </ul>

      <div
        onClick={props.prevModal}
        className="btn dec"
      ></div>

      <div
        className="btn inc"
        onClick={props.nxtModal}
      ></div>

  </div>

)

export default HelperModalRender;
```

## **Container Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import HelperModalRender from './HelperModalRender.js'


class HelperModalContainer extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentSlide: 1,
      slideActive: true
    }

    this.prevModal = this.prevModal.bind(this)
    this.nxtModal = this.nxtModal.bind(this)

  }

  prevModal(){
    var currentSlide = this.state.currentSlide
    this.setState({ currentSlide: currentSlide++ })
  }

  nxtModal(){
    var currentSlide = this.state.currentSlide
    this.setState({ currentSlide: currentSlide-- })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HelperModalRender
        active = {this.state.slideActive}
        currentSlide = {this.state.currentSlide}
        prevModal = {this.state.prevModal}
        nxtModal = {this.state.nxtModal}
      />
    )
  }

}

export default HelperModalContainer;
```

I was hoping to have a function in my container component that would iterate through the `_modals` array, returning the corresponding component - but a switch statement is not an option and I'm having trouble thinking of an alternative.

Comment: As a note <div class="tool-slides active slideshow">... might need to updated to <div className="tool-slides active slideshow">...

Comment: thanks @TylerRafferty - I'm in the process of converting a plain html/js project over to react so that is on my to do list

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but it looks like your container component's render method has a typo.  Try changing HelperModalRender's currentSlide prop to:

```
currentSlide = {this.state.currentSlide}
```

You may also need to start the slides at zero instead of 1, to match the array index of the slide components.

Comment: I actually did make that edit in the code (sorry about that). This is the error I am getting:

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Answer (score 0):

**realized the issue lied in this warning:**

`This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.`

**so I updated the `_modals` array to:**

`const _modals = [ <Modal_1 />, <Modal_2 />, <Modal_3 />, <Modal_4 />, <Modal_5 /> ]`